# I am getting error while changing developer mode to production mode in magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento-2.0.7, di, production-mode

The detail of error is below:

> Enabled maintenance mode
>
> Starting compilation
>
> Something went wrong while compiling generated code. See the error log
>   for details. Command returned non-zero exit code: `/usr/bin/php7.0 -f
>   /var/www/html/magento21/bin/magento setup:di:compile`

My Magento version is 2.1.0

Anyone know regarding this problem then please guide me about various steps need to follow?

Answer (score 1):

Try to run **the Multi-tenant compiler**

```
php -f bin/magento setup:di:compile-multi-tenant -vvv
```

Read more here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-compiler.html

**Note:** if we have a "big" site, we should increase memory limit:

```
php -dmemory_limit=2604M -f bin/magento setup:di:compile-multi-tenant
```

Comment: Hi Khoa, Please open once this url depoto.com . and place order with cod. place order is not working with registered user details. sorry for asking here